# Call operator with auto return type being chosen instead of constructor when using std::function

Tags: c++, c++14, std-function, function-object, return-type-deduction

The following snippet:

```
#include <functional>

struct X {
    X(std::function<double(double)> fn); // (1)
    X(double, double);                   // (2)

    template <class T>
    auto operator()(T const& t) const {  // (3)
        return t.foo();
    }
};

int main() {
    double a, b;
    auto x = X(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

...fails to compile with both `clang` (4.0.1) and `g++` (6.3, 7.2) when using `-std=c++14` — tested on OSX and [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/X7vX5R).

But it compiles without problem if:

- I remove constructor `(1)`;
- or I set the return type to a concrete type (e.g. `double`) in `(3)`;
- or if I use a trailing return type (`-> decltype(t.foo())`) in `(3)`;
- compile using `-std=c++1z` (thanks @bolov).

Maybe there is something obvious that I am missing here... Is there any issue with this code? Is this a bug?

Comment: no error with `C++1z` flag: https://godbolt.org/g/izbzye but seriously, wtf, what is trying to do with `C++14`?

Comment: I'm guessing that `auto x = X{a, b};` is another variant that compiles successfully?

Comment: @TobySpeight Not for me, it fails with the same error.

Comment: @bolov: in C++17, rules has changes (with guaranty copy elision) and code is equivalent to `X x(a, b);`; in C++11, deduced `auto` as return type is not yet supported.

Comment: The same happens in C++17 if one adds the code line `auto y = x`;

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are copy initializing `x`. And `X` is a tricky type for the following reasons:

1. It can be constructed from any callable object that can be called with a double argument. And whose return type is convertible to a double.
2. It is itself a callable object that can be called with a double argument. But the return type needs deducing.
3. There's a compiler generated copy constructor for `X`.

The ambiguity is starting to become obvious here, I hope. There is need for overload resolution.

When your remove the first c'tor, it gets rid of the ambiguity in an obvious fashion. The interesting case is the function call operator.

You see, `std::function` can only be constructed from the callable it is passed (the templated c'tor will only participate in overload resolution) if the conversions between arguments to parameters, and between return types are possible. This is all done in an unevaluated context, so the templated function call operator isn't odr-used, and therefore not instantiated.

When the return type is a placeholder type, the `std::function` c'tor cannot easily resolve if it should be constructed or not. Compilation fails during overload resolution, even though had it succeeded, the copy c'tor of `X` would have been selected.

---

As @VTT suggested in a comment, marking the c'tor that accepts a `std::function` as explicit will also resolve the ambiguity. All on account of the compiler not having to rank the implicit conversion sequence at all.

Comment: @bolov - There are two viable c'tors to construct the object. Except when one is explicitly disqualified.

Comment: Marking constructor that takes function as `explicit` will make it work.

Comment: how is `X(a, b);` considering the `std::function` ctor? It has 2 parameters... And it's not the mvp, because `X{a, b}` has the same behavior.

Comment: @bolov It's clearer if you write `X x1(a, b); X x2 = x1;`, the issue is the construction of `x2` from `x1`.

Comment: @Holt and the light bulb lightened up. thank you. @ StoryTeller maybe you could give some more clarifications. I don't think I am the one who still didn't get it from your answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, I do understand the root of the issue, but I don't understand of it ends up to this - Shouldn't the copy-constructor be an better match here? In which case, why would the constructor of `std::function<double(double)>(X)` be instantiated?

Comment: @Holt - It is. But the problem is that overload resolution must still happen, and the placeholder type interferes with checking that `std::function` should be disqualified.